# R: pheatmap reorder columns while maintaining topology

Tags: r, cluster-computing, pheatmap

I would like to change the column order of my heat map created with the R package `pheatmap`, but keep the same topology so that the dendrogram on top also reorders with the columns.

While explained in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/pheatmap.pdf), I can't figure out how to implement it in R.

Comment: By default, `pheatmap` would cluster rows and columns unless you set arguments `cluster_rows` and `cluster_cols` to `FALSE`. To achieve custom order of the columns, you need to re-structure your `data.frame` and set `cluster_cols=FALSE`. Similar operation can be done to rows.

Comment: I still need my columns to be clustered, but I want to flip around some of the nodes in my dendogram, so that the columns are in a different order.

Comment: You could explore by implementing `x <- pheatmap(...)`. This should give you a list object. Though a bit tricky, try to see if you can overwrite some options and then plot.

Comment: @SamVanbergen did you find and answer to this? I have the same issue